# Rails and SQLITE3 problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows-xp, chiliproject

I am trying to install "ChiliProject" on my Windows XP SP3. Everything was fine until I tried to process the db:migrate.

> C:\RubyApps\chiliproject>bundle exec rake db:migrate

Then I get the error:

> rake aborted!
>   no such file to load -- sqlite3

I have the sqlite3 gem installed:

> sqlite3 (1.3.4 x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32-60)

The three files: sqlite3.exe, sqlite3.dll, sqlite3.def from sqlite.org are put in the "C:\Ruby192\bin" directory (which is my default ruby dir).

The database configuration is (database.yml):

```
production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.db
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have "sqlite3-ruby" gem installed in your system?

Comment: No, only "sqlite3" gem. However, I have tried to install sqlite3-ruby but the result is the same: "no such file to load -- sqlite3".

Comment: This is a known bug which will be resolved for the 2.3.0 release due at the end of next week. Please refer to https://www.chiliproject.org/issues/617 and https://www.chiliproject.org/projects/chiliproject/versions/16 for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to this post http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=40674 you probably need to add

`gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'`
to your Gemfile,

and after that try to run `bundle package` and `rake db:create` and finally `rake db:migrate`

Comment: I case anyone finds this later on, we fixed the Gemfile in ChiliProject 2.3.0 to be fully compatible with the mingw ruby commonly used on Windows. The change of the Gemfile shouldn't be necessary any more.